# Can somebody explain this regular expression?

Tags: regex, qt, syntax

I'm reading a Qt example to understand syntax highlighting. I'm not able to understand this:

```
QRegExp exp("//[^\n]*");
```

Please explain it.

Answer (score 9):

Two slashes, then zero or more characters that are anything except a newline. That looks like a regular expression to match a comment, eg:

```
// this is a comment
```

- `//` simply means the literal sequence of two slashes.
- Something inside square brackets is a group. If it begins with `^` it means "not in this group". `\n` means newline, so `[^\n]` means "any character except a newline".
- An asterisk, `*`, roughly means "zero or more of the preceding character or group".

The [QRegExp documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qregexp.html) has a pretty decent writeup. Just be methodical and work your way from left to right in order to understand what a pattern means.